# C# get and set the high order word of an integer

Tags: c#

What's an efficient or syntactically simple way to get and set the high order part of an integer?

Comment: The size of a normal integer is typically the word size of a machine.  Do you mean the high order bytes or perhaps the high order word of a long?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's the same as in C/C++:

```
// get the high order 16 bits
int high = 0x12345678 >> 16; // high = 0x1234
// set the high order 16 bits
high = (high & 0x0000FFFF) + (0x5678 << 16); // high = 0x56781234
```

**EDIT:** Because I'm in a good mood, here you go. Just remember, immutable types are immutable! The 'set' functions need to be assigned to something.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public int LowWord(this int number)
    { return number & 0x0000FFFF; }
    public int LowWord(this int number, int newValue)
    { return (number & 0xFFFF0000) + (newValue & 0x0000FFFF); }
    public int HighWord(this int number)
    { return number & 0xFFFF0000; }
    public int HighWord(this int number, int newValue)
    { return (number & 0x0000FFFF) + (newValue << 16); }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** On second thoughts, if you really need to do this and don't want the syntax everywhere, use Michael's solution. +1 to him for showing me something new.

Comment: If you need these a lot, and if you are nostalgic of C days, you can create static methods for these, called LoWord(), HiWord(), LoByte() and HiByte().  I'm surprised that these ol' macros equivalent were not made somehow part of some .NET class such as Int.

Comment: This uses computing power, which is a waste. At compile time the desired bit pattern is already somewhere on stack and we can tell the compiler exactly where this bit pattern is, so it can be copied without any calculations. Use System.BitConverter for this.

Answer (score 38):

There are multiple ways of achieving that, here are some of them.

---

### Using the [Bitwise and/or Shift operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators)

Applying a right shift in an integer will move the bits to the right, putting zeros to the left.
In the case below, it will shift the size of a short (Int16, as 16 bits).

Applying a logical AND (&) operation in an integer like `0x0000FFFF` will basically 'cut' the value (where it's `F`) and ignore the rest (where it's `0`).
Remember that in the end it's just a `0b_1 AND 0b_1 = 0b_1` operation, so any `0b_0 AND 0b_1` will result in `0b_0`.

Applying a logical OR (|) operation will basically merge the two numbers in this case, like `0b_10 | 0b_01 = 0b_11`.

Code:

```
uint number = 0xDEADBEEF;

//Get the higher order value.
var high = number >> 16;
Console.WriteLine($"High: {high:X}");

//Get the lower order value.
var low = number & 0xFFFF; //Or use 0x0000FFFF
Console.WriteLine($"Low: {low:X}");

//Set a high order value (you can also use 0xFFFF instead of 0x0000FFFF).
uint newHigh = 0xFADE;
number = number & 0x0000FFFF | newHigh << 16;
Console.WriteLine($"New high: {number:X}");

//Set a low order value.
uint newLow = 0xC0DE;
number = number & 0xFFFF0000 | newLow & 0x0000FFFF;
Console.WriteLine($"New low: {number:X}");
```

Output:

```
High: DEAD
Low: BEEF
New high: FADEBEEF
New low: FADEC0DE
```

---

### Using [FieldOffsetAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute) in a struct

C# has excellent support for variables sharing the same memory location, and bits structuring.

Since C# has no **macro** functions like in C, you can use the **union** approach to speed things up. It's more performant than passing the variable to methods or extension methods.

You can do that by simply creating a [struct with explicit layout and setting the offset of the fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acxa5b99):

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct WordUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint Number;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ushort Low;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public ushort High;
}
    
public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {        
        var x = new WordUnion { Number = 0xABADF00D };
        Console.WriteLine("{0:X} {1:X} {2:X}", x.Number, x.High, x.Low);

        x.Low = 0xFACE;
        Console.WriteLine("{0:X} {1:X} {2:X}", x.Number, x.High, x.Low);

        x.High = 0xDEAD;
        Console.WriteLine("{0:X} {1:X} {2:X}", x.Number, x.High, x.Low);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ABADF00D ABAD F00D
ABADFACE ABAD FACE
DEADFACE DEAD FACE
```

> Mind that with Visual Studio 2029 (16.7), you still may get zeros in `x.High` and `x.Low` when adding the variable `x` inside the Watch or by hovering your cursor on top of the variables `x.High` and `x.Low` directly.

> [image: Visual Studio Bug]

---

### Using unsafe and [pointer element access operator []](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/pointer-related-operators#pointer-element-access-operator-)

To a more akin to C programming, but in C#, use `unsafe`:

Code:

```
unsafe
{
    uint value = 0xCAFEFEED;

    // x86 is using low-endian. 
    // So low order array number gets the low order of the value
    // And high order array number gets the high order of the value
    Console.WriteLine("Get low order of {0:X}: {1:X}", 
        value, ((ushort*) &value)[0]);

    Console.WriteLine("Get high order of {0:X}: {1:X}", 
        value, ((ushort*) &value)[1]);


    ((ushort*) &value)[1] = 0xABAD;
    Console.WriteLine("Set high order to ABAD: {0:X}", value);

    ((ushort*) &value)[0] = 0xFACE;
    Console.WriteLine("Set low order to FACE: {0:X}", value);
}
```

Output:

```
Get low order of CAFEFEED: FEED
Get high order of CAFEFEED: CAFE
Set high order to ABAD: ABADFEED
Set low order to FACE: ABADFACE
```

---

### Using unsafe and [pointer member access operator ->](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/pointer-related-operators#pointer-member-access-operator--)

Another `unsafe` approach, but this time accessing a member from the `WordUnion` struct declared in a previous example:

Code:

```
unsafe
{
    uint value = 0xCAFEFEED;

    Console.WriteLine("Get low order of {0:X}: {1:X}", 
        value, ((WordUnion*) &value)->Low);

    Console.WriteLine("Get high order of {0:X}: {1:X}", 
        value, ((WordUnion*) &value)->High);


    ((WordUnion*) &value)->High = 0xABAD;
    Console.WriteLine($"Set high order to ABAD: {value:X}");

    ((WordUnion*) &value)->Low = 0xFACE;
    Console.WriteLine($"Set low order to FACE: {value:X}");
}
```

Output:

```
Get low order of CAFEFEED: FEED
Get high order of CAFEFEED: CAFE
Set high order to ABAD: ABADFEED
Set low order to FACE: ABADFACE
```

---

### Using the [BitConverter class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter)

It simply gets 16 bits (2 bytes, a `short`/`Int16`) from the specified number. The offset can be controlled by the second parameter.

Code:

```
uint value = 0xCAFEFEED;

var low = BitConverter.ToInt16(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0);
var high = BitConverter.ToInt16(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 2);

Console.WriteLine($"Low: {low:X}");
Console.WriteLine($"High: {high:X}");
```

Output:

```
Low: 0xCAFE
High: 0xFEED
```

Comment: +1 for showing me something new. Now I have something new to abuse.

Comment: This one is extremely useful and clever! It is much more simple to use and works easily both for getting and for setting the low and high order values. Thanks a lot for sharing this knowledge!

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Just a warning, `VS 16.7` ignores `FieldOffset` attributes inside the `Watch`, at least that's what I believe. So, `High` and `Low` fields will be zero.

Comment: @NickeManarin nice, you already filed the bug to Visual Studio team

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1145379/watch-cant-properly-resolve-struct-with-numbers-wi.html

Comment: Yes, and I just discovered when visiting this page. :)

Comment: Not sure how I'm the first to comment on this but...  Visual Studio 2029 (16.7) huh?  Must be a special kind of entity to achieve gaining access to such an early release.  :)

Comment: @ArvoBowen Hahah I noticed that too long time ago, but Stack Overflow does not allow correcting text errors that are just 1 character. Let them suffer with that folly policy lol :D

Answer (score 5):

I guess you don't want calculations when you want the Hiword / Hibyte or the LoWord / Lobyte,
if a System.Int32 starts at address 100 (so it occupies address 100 to 103), you want as a LoWord the two bytes starting at address 100 and 101 and Hiword is address 102 and 103.

This can be achieved using the class BitConverter. This class doesn't do anything with the bits, it only uses the addresses to return the requested value.

As the size of types like int / long are different per platform, and WORD and DWORD are a bit confusing, I use the System types System.Int16/Int32/Int64. No one will ever have any problems guessing the number of bits in a System.Int32.

With BitConverter you can convert any integer to the array of bytes starting on that location and convert an array of bytes of the proper length to the corresponding integer. No calculations needed and no bits will change,

Suppose you have a System.Int32 X (which is a DWORD in old terms)

```
LOWORD: System.Int16 y = BitConverter.ToInt16(BitConverter.GetBytes(x), 0);
HIWORD: System.Int16 y = BitConverter.ToInt16(BitConverter.GetBytes(x), 2);
```

The nice thing is that this works with all lengths, you don't have to combine functions like LOBYTE and HIWORD to get the third byte:

```
HIByte(Hiword(x)) will be like: BitConverter.GetBytes(x)[3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another Alternative

```
    public class Macro
    {
        public static short MAKEWORD(byte a, byte b)
        {
            return ((short)(((byte)(a & 0xff)) | ((short)((byte)(b & 0xff))) << 8));
        }

        public static byte LOBYTE(short a)
        {
            return ((byte)(a & 0xff));
        }

        public static byte HIBYTE(short a)
        {
            return ((byte)(a >> 8));
        }

        public static int MAKELONG(short a, short b)
        {
            return (((int)(a & 0xffff)) | (((int)(b & 0xffff)) << 16));
        }

        public static short HIWORD(int a)
        {
            return ((short)(a >> 16));
        }

        public static short LOWORD(int a)
        {
            return ((short)(a & 0xffff));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Great!

Answer (score 0):

I use these 2 function...

```
    public static int GetHighint(long intValue)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(intValue >> 32);
    }

    public static int GetLowint(long intValue)
    {
        long tmp = intValue << 32;
        return Convert.ToInt32(tmp >> 32);
    }
```