# converting C to C#

Tags: c#, c, struct, unions

I'm trying to convert this C code to C#, is there a C# equivalent to the C union typedef?

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short   sin_family;
    u_short sin_port;
    struct  in_addr sin_addr;
    char    sin_zero[8];
};

typedef struct in_addr {
  union {
    struct {
      u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4;
    } S_un_b;
    struct {
      u_short s_w1,s_w2;
    } S_un_w;
    u_long S_addr;
  } S_un;
 } IN_ADDR, *PIN_ADDR, FAR *LPIN_ADDR;
```

Thanks.

Comment: This code appears to be for TCP/IP handling code.  C# has it's own TCP/IP handling, and therefore you don't need to do this.  Unless you're trying to do something very low level, in which case C# is not your best choice.  What exactly is the code used for?  And no, there is no equivelent of union in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check out the [following page](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/SOCKADDR.html). This being said, in .NET you have classes that allows you to work directly with sockets and TCP/IP such as Socket, TcpListener, TcpClient and you don't need to translate C code blindly.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst the others definitely have a point - this is likely something you *really* don't need to do - there **is** a way to simulate unions in C# using [StructLayoutAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) (example of simulating a union [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).

But don't do it. The purpose of this C union seems to be to permit bit twiddling parts of a 4 byte long. Using a union in this way depends on byte order knowledge of the target architecture, something that C# cannot guarantee.

In C# - or any other language where portability is a concern - if you want to get or set the high byte/low byte/etc you need to use explicit bit shifting as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436190/c-sharp-get-and-set-the-high-order-word-of-an-integer).

But then don't do that either. Do like others have said and don't port this code. Someone's already done it for you, most likely Microsoft in the built in libraries ;).