# converting C to C#

Tags: c#, c, casting, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [converting C to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292313/converting-c-to-c-sharp)

i have problem in converting by c code to c#
i hav two structers

```
  struct sockaddr {
      ushort  sa_family;
      char    sa_data[14];
  };

struct sockaddr_in {
    short   sin_family;
    u_short sin_port;
    struct  in_addr sin_addr;
    char    sin_zero[8];
};
```

and i use to cast it like this...
to get the ip address. from the sockaddr_in structure

```
 ip = inet_ntoa((( sockaddr_in*)name)->sin_addr);
```

now i converted the structure in c# as

```
 public struct sockaddr
    {
         public static ushort sa_family;            
         public static char[] sa_data = new char[14];

    };
```

and..

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 16)]
     public struct sockaddr_in
     {
         public const int Size = 16;

         public short sin_family;
         public ushort sin_port;
         public struct in_addr
         {
             public uint S_addr;
             public struct _S_un_b
             {
                 public byte s_b1, s_b2, s_b3, s_b4;
             }
             public _S_un_b S_un_b;
             public struct _S_un_w
             {
                 public ushort s_w1, s_w2;
             }
             public _S_un_w S_un_w;
         }
         public in_addr sin_addr;
     }
```

can any one plz help me to get ip address from casting the sockaddr to sockaddr_in as i tried it in c... its working fine... how do i do the same in C#...

thanks u in Advance..

Comment: I think that you're going to miss out on a lot of C# functionality by performing a straight conversion C to C#. In this instance C# has its own socket handling class

Comment: What is your reason for passing these structures between C and C#? C# has built-in networking classes.

Comment: If that is your way to switch to C# I would recommend to leave it in C and use as unmanaged code. With such an approach you gain nothing from implementing it in C#.

BTW. is what you are trying to achieve just to parse string to ushort and in_addr?

Comment: The solution to the problem is surely not to do this and use the .net library. If you really want to write C, then write C.

Comment: On a related note: can somebody help me convert Java to Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to achieve is certainly possible in C#. Here is an example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
unsafe struct SockAddr {
    public ushort sa_family;
    public fixed byte sa_data[14]; // Note: sizeof(char) == 2 in C#
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
unsafe struct SockAddr_In {
    public short sin_family;
    public ushort sin_port;
    public In_Addr sin_addr;
    public fixed byte sin_zero[8];
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct In_Addr {
    public byte s_b1, s_b2, s_b3, s_b4;
}

public static unsafe void CStyle() {
    SockAddr s;
    SockAddr* ps = &s;

    SockAddr_In* psa = (SockAddr_In*)ps;

    var inAddr = new In_Addr();

    inAddr.s_b1 = 192;
    inAddr.s_b2 = 168;
    inAddr.s_b3 = 168;
    inAddr.s_b4 = 56;
    psa->sin_addr = inAddr;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", 
                       psa->sin_addr.s_b1, psa->sin_addr.s_b2, 
                       psa->sin_addr.s_b3, psa->sin_addr.s_b4);
}
```

However as others have pointed out, such approaches lead to non-idiomatic C# code and cannot generally be recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a low level socket connection, but Microsoft wraps everything you need in two classes called HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse which are located in the System.Net namespace.

```
private Socket m_socket = null;
internal void Connect()
{
    m_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(Dns.Resolve(this.EndPointUri.Host).AddressList[0], EndPointUri.Port);
    m_socket.Connect(remoteEP);

    m_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, 60 * 1000);
    m_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 60 * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is called Marshaling.

You'll probably have to add some Tips to the structure to make sure it gets marshaled correctly. (Are the C++ char and C# char of compatible types? etc)

Comment: This should be a comment. It does not answer the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sometimes you don't need an answer, you just need to know where to look. Any way since you're completely right +1 for you :D